# How to pass arguments from a windows 10 scheduled task to a powershell script onLock and onUnlock events/triggers

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to setup the following scenario using a windows 10 task scheduler.

1. A logged in user locks or unlocks the workstation
2. A powershell script gets triggered and the PC-NAME and a USER_NAME of a user who's locking/unlocking workstation parameters.

How or where one can find some documentation or example of how to accomplish #2?

I know how to trigger batch files or powershell scripts, but cannot figure out a way to grab parameters from the triggered task/event.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So the information you want to pass from the scheduled task to the powerscript is the username and pcname? `Get-ComputerName` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085744/how-do-i-get-the-current-username-in-windows-powershell

Comment: @Gantendo Yes, that's correct Computer name and the username. Would the answer above give me the username of the user that has been just locked? I guess I have to try to test that soon.

Comment: @Gantendo Ok so I ran the test and the user I get extracted by doing   [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name 
 is actually the user who owns/runs the task and NOT the user who locks or unlocks the workstation. Any idea how I can get that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I think I have figured it out

The following script is to be ran at lock/onlock of the workstation.

```
$username = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
$pcName = [System.Environment]::MachineName
$file = "c:\Scripts\ps-output.txt"

Write-Host $username
Write-Host $pcName

Add-Content -Path $file -Value "Login"
Add-Content -Path $file -Value $username
Add-Content -Path $file -Value $pcName
```

In order for it to register the user who locks and unlocks the workstation I had to do the following changes to the General section of the scheduled task.

[Screenshot of the General section of the task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTO09.png)

In my case the INTERACTIVE run context wasn't selectable so I had to edit the exported XML with  and reimport the task.

Group ID had to be *S-1-5-4*

XML portion

```xml
<Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <GroupId>S-1-5-4</GroupId>
      <RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
```